# Can't find view in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to develop an eclipse plugin, and I have implemented a view.  When I ran this project as an eclipse application, I was able to find the view with Show View < Other < Sample Category < Sample View.  Then I made a different project in the same project explorer, and now when I run as a an eclipse application, the second view is the only one that shows up under Sample Category.  How can I get the first view back?

Comment: When you opened up the second project, did it change perspectives?

Comment: Are both the plug-ins being included in the Eclipse application `Run Configuration`? Do the views have different ids?

Comment: The views had the same id, among other similarities.  I changed them and now it works! Thanks!